# Paho-MQTT check message queue size

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I'm publishing MQTT messages from an Arduino, and subscribing to those from a Raspberry Pi. Sometimes the publishing goes faster than the Raspberry can receive (and process).

I'm looking for a way of checking how many messages are queued on the Raspberry side. I'm using [Paho-MQTT](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/). I only see it is possible to set a max queue size, but how can I check the current queue size? (If possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no queue in the broker, all messages are delivered as they are published.

The Paho client is singled threaded and the Message received call back is handled on the network thread, so messages may back up on the network stack (for QOS0 messages). QOS1/2 messages will back up in the broker until the QOS handshake for the current message completes.

The max_queued message setting is about how many QOS 1/2 messages the client will accept to publish before blocking, not how many incoming messages it will queue up.

If you want to queue messages in a measurable way then have the Message received callback place the messages on to a local queue and have a second thread (or pool of threads if they can be handled in parallel) take messages from the local queue.

Comment: Thank you, but could you ellaborate on the last part of your answer? "have the message received callback place the messages..."


Also, it is the raspberry pi that hosts the network. Are there perhaps some mosquitto commands that may give me information about the queues?

Comment: I don't write enough python to give you a decent example, but queuing work for a thread to consume is standard enough for you to search for. No, there is no way to ask the broker, because it doesn't track it at all.